# onclick to halt previous video and play new one

Tags: javascript, video

Single video frame populated by specific calls to different videos. Only problem is that when new video is called via button click, the previously playing video does not stop until the new video is started. I'm thinking I should be able to add a single line in the script to stop or pause the previous video, but not sure of syntax or placement.

[The page is here](https://www.krayvankirk.com/media).

```
<div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openVideo(event, 'The Walls of Jerusalem')" id="defaultOpen">The Walls of Jerusalem</button> 
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openVideo(event, 'The Queen of Elfland')">The Queen of Efland</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openVideo(event, 'The House About Kirk Michael')">The House About Kirk Michael</button> 
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openVideo(event, 'Lost Lovers Waltz')"> Lost Lovers Waltz</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openVideo(event, 'I Am a Knight')"> I Am a Knight</button> 
</div>

  <script>
function openVideo(evt, videoName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(videoName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

</script>
```

Video calls

```
    <div id="The Walls of Jerusalem" class="tabcontent"> 
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/752803111?h=126276ec5f" width="640" height="564" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>

<div id="The Queen of Elfland" class="tabcontent">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/141960358?h=4b0a28a64a" width="640" height="564" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>  </div>
```

and so on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is telling the browser not to display the old video when you switch to the new one, but it is not asking it to stop playing the video.

Vimeo, your video hosting service and video player, provides and API to allow you pause a video to stop it playing which should do what you want.

You can find details on this and the other Vimeo player API's and config here: https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#embed-options

> // If you want to control the embeds, you’ll need to create a Player object.
>
> // You can pass either the `<div>` or the `<iframe>` created inside the div.

For example:

```js
var video = document.getElementById('yourCurrentVideoDiv_or_iFrame');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(video);
player.pause()
```